# Sorting case statement DESC in sql

Tags: sql, sorting, sql-server-express

I want to sorting my ArticleID down to up(DESC). How can i edit this code to do that?
thank you so much

```
ORDER  BY CASE 
        WHEN @order = 'AddArticleType.ArticleID' THEN CONVERT(nvarchar,AddArticleType.ArticleID) 
        WHEN @order = 'Title' THEN CONVERT(nvarchar, Title) 
        WHEN @order = 'family' THEN CONVERT(nvarchar, family)
        WHEN @order = 'AddArticleType.ArticleType' THEN 
         CONVERT(nvarchar, AddArticleType.ArticleType ) 
      END
```

Comment: Is this for SQL Server? If so, what version? Also, it would help if you posted the rest of your SQL query.

Comment: No it is for SQL exppress..

Comment: @SaeedTalaee: Why this question has `asp.net` tag on it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going back to @Gordon's good answer from your previous post, this should work:

```
ORDER  BY 
   CASE WHEN @order = 'AddArticleType.ArticleID' THEN AddArticleType.ArticleID END DESC,
   CASE WHEN @order = 'Title' THEN Title END,
   CASE WHEN @order = 'family' THEN family END,
   CASE WHEN @order = 'AddArticleType.ArticleType' THEN AddArticleType.ArticleType END
```

I've simplified your code for testing:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a2d3/9

Good luck.